# Handle DTD with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, dtd

I have built this DTD :

```
<!ELEMENT universes (universe+)>
<!ELEMENT universe (index,name,conf)>
<!ELEMENT index (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT conf (speed,resources-cdr,moons,bots)>
<!ELEMENT speed (game,fleet,resources)> 
<!ELEMENT game (#PCDATA)> 
<!ELEMENT fleet (#PCDATA)> 
<!ELEMENT resources (#PCDATA)> 
<!ELEMENT resources-cdr (ships,defs) > 
<!ELEMENT ships (#PCDATA)> 
<!ELEMENT defs (#PCDATA)> 
<!ELEMENT moons (#PCDATA)> 
<!ELEMENT bots (#PCDATA)>
```

and I use it inside a xml file like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE universes SYSTEM "universes.dtd" >
```

Now under Eclipse (indigo) when I use `CTRL+SPACE` to see elements list, I see simple elements only (those #PCDATA) not others. See below :

[image]

In this case, I see `index` and `name` proposals but not `conf` proposal.

If I enter `conf` tag manually, not with wizard, I have similar problem with nested tags :

[image]

How can I modify this Eclipse behaviour please ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok problem is solved.

In my case, I have created xml file **before** linking it with its DTD.

If I create new xml file with Eclipse and choose `create XML file from a DTD` it's work